# How to run php tests in Laravel project for my own package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have my own Laravel package and I want to be able to write and create tests for it.

My project is installed on the following directory within my project `ROOT/CompayName/package-name`. My tests are located in `ROOT/CompanyName/package-name/tests` while the code is located in  `ROOT/CompanyName/package-name/src`.

In the `composer.json` file I autoload my tests like this

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/",
        "CompayName\\ProjectName\\": "CompayName/package-name/tests/"
    }
},
```

Additionally, I added the following to the `phpunit.xml` file

```
<testsuite name="Unit">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./CompanyName/project-name/tests/</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Then I create the following test

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ProjectName;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class SomeKindOfTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function ableToDoSomething()
    {       
        dd('ableToDoSomething was called!!!!!!!!!!!');
    }
}
```

However, when I run `phpunit` from the command line, my test isn't being fired!

How can I correctly fire the tests in my package.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit usually runs the methods named `test*`, unless you have specified otherwise in phpunit.xml.

Try renaming your test:

```php
public function testAbleToDoSomething() {}
```

PHPUnit also supports a special `/** @test */` annotation inside the docblock:

```php
/** @test */
public function ableToDoSomething() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried renaming the method to start with the keyword `test` and I also tried to decorate it with the `/** @test */` but still now working.